# Need Discord Bot to Delete Previous Message

Tags: python, discord

I am coding a discord bot that to use will require lots of commands, so it clogs up a channel pretty quickly. Here is some example code that in theory should work.

```
    @commands.command() 
     async def play(self,ctx,url):
         ctx.voice_client.stop()
         FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 - 
         reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
         YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
         vc = ctx.voice_client


    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,
      **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
      await ctx.message.delete()
```

This example works, however this one sometimes works but sometimes doesn't and I have no idea why.

```
@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
  else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
```

I am really confused as to why it doesn't work, all I want it to do is delete the previous message so it doesn't block up channels.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.Py has a `delete_after` kwarg that takes the amount of seconds to delete the sent message after, for example

```py
await channel.send("this message will be deleted after 10 seconds", delete_after=10)
```

You can use this arg in any `ctx.send` message so it will auto delete after a specific amount of time.

Comment: This does not delete the previous message though